# Python loop and add to dictionary until blank line in file

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to add position, name, classrooms until blank from a file using:

> Get-Content in.txt | python school.py

Example in.txt:

```
supervisor
Jack
1a
1b
2a
```

- 

```
supervisor_list = []
supervisor_dict = {}
def user_type():
    check_who = input()
    if check_who == "supervisor":
        name = input()
        check_class = input()
        supervisor_dict["User"] = check_who
        supervisor_dict["Name"] = name
        supervisor_dict["School_class"] = check_class
        check_class = input()
        while not check_class.isspace():
            supervisor_dict["School_class"] += " " + check_class
            supervisor_list.append(supervisor_dict)
            check_class = input()
```

could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your terminal argument to have something to identify, otherwise you're just running out of lines.

This will stop at the end, or at a blank line.

```bash
(Get-Content in.txt) + '' | python school.py
```

`school.py`

```py
supervisor_list = []
def user_type():
    supervisor_dict = {
        'User': input(),
        'Name': input(),
        'School_class': input()
    }
    if supervisor_dict["User"] == "supervisor":
        while (check_class := input()):
            supervisor_dict["School_class"] += ' ' + check_class
        supervisor_list.append(supervisor_dict)

user_type()
print(supervisor_list)
```

Output:

```py
[{'User': 'supervisor', 'Name': 'Jack', 'School_class': '1a 1b 2a'}]
```

---

Alternative, if we can't change the input, let's keep going until the error, or a blank line:

```bash
Get-Content in.txt | python school.py
```

`school.py`

```py
supervisor_list = []
def user_type():
    supervisor_dict = {
        'User': input(),
        'Name': input(),
        'School_class': input()
    }
    if supervisor_dict["User"] == "supervisor":
        while True:
            try:
                if not (check_class := input()) : break
            except EOFError : break   
            supervisor_dict["School_class"] += ' ' + check_class
        supervisor_list.append(supervisor_dict)  

user_type()
print(supervisor_list)
```

Comment: Well, I think I explained what the code needs to do. As for the output I can manage. The program needs to import from the terminal. Thanks

Comment: @letsgamble updated my answer to work with terminal input from `Get-Content`~

Answer (score 0):

`check_class.isspace()` checks if the string is a empty space, like " ". If you want to check if a line is empty, just use `check_class == ''` or, if you want to accept as empty line a line with white spaces, use `check_class.strip() == ''`

Answer (score 0):

code `check_class.isspace()` will check if a string empty '' if you want to check a line is blank you can try `check_class == ''` and if you want to check if string contains any spaces in it than `(' ' in check_class) == True`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should run the function. If you want the user to type in the data via command line, this would be a possible solution:

```py
supervisor_list = []
supervisor_dict = {}
stop_character = ""


def user_type():
    check_who = input()
    if check_who == "supervisor":
        name = input()
        check_class = input()
        supervisor_dict["User"] = check_who
        supervisor_dict["Name"] = name
        supervisor_dict["School_class"] = check_class
        while True:
            check_class = input()
            if check_class == stop_character:
                break
            supervisor_dict["School_class"] += " " + check_class
        supervisor_list.append(supervisor_dict)

user_type()
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it gives me: `PS C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\schooldatabase> Get-Content in.txt | python school.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\schooldatabase\school.py", line 33, in <module>
    user_type()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\schooldatabase\school.py", line 17, in user_type
    check_class = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Answer (score 0):

You may want it to write like this

```
supervisor_list = []
supervisor_dict = {}
def user_type():
    check_who = input("Enter user type: ")
    if check_who == "supervisor" or check_who == "Supervisor":
        name = input("Enter name: ")
        check_class = input("Enter class: ")
        supervisor_dict["User"] = check_who
        supervisor_dict["Name"] = name
        supervisor_dict["School_class"] = check_class
        while not check_class.isspace():
            supervisor_dict["School_class"] += " " + check_class
            check_class = input("Enter class: ")
        supervisor_list.append(supervisor_dict)
    
    return supervisor_list
```